# Как связать коллекции? и как вывести время (из коллекции) в паре с количеством фильмов?

Tags: c#

*Только начал учить с#*

> Коллекция "Показ" имеет следующую структуру: код фильма, название кинотеатра, время начала. В элементах коллекции "Фильмы" хранятся код и название фильма и перечень исполнителей, задействованных в фильме. выполнить
> следующие задачи:
>
> 1. Для каждого времени начала вывести количество фильмов, которые начинаются в это время.
> 2. Вывести без повторов названия фильмов, которые показывают в по крайней мере трех различных кинотеатрах.

Как связать коллекции? и как вывести время(из коллекции) в паре с количеством фильмов?

Comment: Поскольку вы не приводите код, а только слова русского языка (которые к тому же не ваши, а цитата из техзадания) то и ответ будет не кодом, а такими же словами: связывайте коллекции по общему ключу (код фильма). Вывод в паре -- это дополнительный цикл внутри внешнего, неважно как организован - через классический цикл или через linq.

Comment: Начинайте писать код. Создайте два класса: Фильм и Показ, сделайте в них необходимые свойства. Создайте две коллекции этих классов. Заполните коллекции данными.